# LaTeX: Aling table in landscape page

Tags: latex

How can I left-align the following table and center the heading and number of pages?
Also, currently the lines within the table have disappeared and the table should be covering the whole page...

(as this is my first post, the picture cannot be shown here due to stackoverflow policy, see the link below)

Thanks in advance for your smart help! :)

```
\KOMAoptions{paper={landscape},pagesize}
\recalctypearea

\hypertarget{Systeme}{\section{Gängige Systeme}}

\begin{table}[!h]
\resizebox{\columnwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabularx}{15cm}{|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l|l}
\hline
\textbf{Name} &
  \textbf{XR-type} &
  \textbf{Standalone} &
  \textbf{Jahr} &
  \textbf{Preis} &
  \textbf{Display} &
  \textbf{Sehwinkel} &
  \textbf{Auflösung /Auge} &
  \textbf{Bildrate} &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{Sonstiges} \\ \hline
Oculus Quest 2 &
  VR &
  ja &
  2020 &
  \$299 &
  Single Fast switch LCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}97° horizontal\\ 93° vertical\end{tabular} &
  1832x1920 &
  120 Hz &
   \\ \cline{1-9}
Pico Neo 3 Link &
  VR &
  ja &
  2022 &
  \$449 &
  Single LCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}98° horizontal\\ 90° vertical\end{tabular} &
  1832x1920 &
  90 Hz &
   \\ \hline
VRgineers XTAL 3 Mixed Reality &
  MR &
  nein &
  2022 &
  \$11500 &
  2 x LCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}180° horizontal\\ 90° vertical\end{tabular} &
  3840x2160 &
  120 Hz &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{6 DoF Inside-out} \\ \hline
VRgineers XTAL 3 &
  VR &
  nein &
   &
  \$8900 &
  2 x LCD &
  \begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}180° horizontal\\ 90° vertical\end{tabular} &
  3840x2160 &
  120 Hz &
   \\ \cline{1-9}
Dream Glass Lead Pro &
  AR &
  ja &
  2022 &
  \$1199 &
   &
  90° diagonal &
  1920x1080 &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-9}
Tilt Five &
  AR &
  nein &
  2021 &
  \$359 &
  2 x LCoS &
  110° diagonal &
  1280x720 &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-9}
Lenovo ThinkReality A3 &
  AR &
  nein &
  2021 &
  \$1499 &
   &
   &
  1920x1080 &
   &
   \\ \cline{1-9}
HTC Vive Flow &
  VR &
  ja &
  2021 &
  \$499 &
  2 x LCD &
  100° diagonal &
  1600x1600 &
  75 Hz &
   \\ \hline
Huawei VR Glass 6DoF &
  MR &
  nein &
  2021 &
  \$620 &
  2 x LCD &
  90° diagonal &
  1600x1600 &
  90 Hz &
  \multicolumn{1}{l|}{6 DoF Inside-out via 2 Kameras} \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}%
}
\end{table}
```

[image: the current table]

Comment: Please make a compilable [mre], including a documentclass etc. so we know the exact geometry of your pages.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please make sure you provide the full code that anyone can compile and test. It's usually not even possible to help without it!

---

Your table is simply too wide. The only sensible way to fit it within a page is to change wording; sometimes breaking into multiple lines can be enough. For the latter, inner `tabular` is OK but I would suggest [makecell](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/makecell) package.

The culprits are headings and repeated information (horizontal, vertical or diagonal). I'd change long headings to acronyms and add annotations at the bottom unless a particular heading name is already short or takes similar space as most of the cell content.

Here's the proposed example:

[image]

and the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{makecell} 

\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\NewDocumentCommand\xtnote{sm}{\def\tss{\textsuperscript{#2}}\IfBooleanTF{#1}{\tss}{\rlap{\tss}}}
\newcommand\emspace{\hspace{0.75em}}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\cellalign{cc}
\renewcommand\theadalign{cc}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
  \setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l *8{c} X}
    \toprule
    \thead[l]{Name} &
    \thead{XR\\type} &
    \thead{ST\,\xtnote{1}} &   % Standalone
    \thead{Jahr} &
    \thead{Preis} &
    \thead[l]{Display} &
    \thead{SE\,\xtnote{2}} &   % Sehwinkel
    \thead{Auflösung\\Auge} &
    \thead{Bildrate} &
    \thead{Sonstiges} \\\midrule
    Oculus Quest 2 &
    VR &
    ja &
    2020 &
    \$299 &
    \makecell{Single Fast\\switch LCD} &
    \makecell{97° \xtnote{h}\\93° \xtnote{v}} &
    1832x1920 &
    120 Hz & \\
    Pico Neo 3 Link &
    VR &
    ja &
    2022 &
    \$449 &
    Single LCD &
    \makecell{98° \xtnote{h}\\90° \xtnote{v}} &
    1832x1920 &
    90 Hz & \\
    \makecell[l]{VRgineers XTAL 3\\Mixed Reality} &
    MR &
    nein &
    2022 &
    \$11500 &
    2 x LCD &
    \makecell{180° \xtnote{h}\\90° \xtnote{v}} &
    3840x2160 &
    120 Hz &
    6 DoF Inside-out \\
    VRgineers XTAL 3 &
    VR &
    nein &
         &
    \$8900 &
    2 x LCD &
    \makecell{180° \xtnote{h}\\90° \xtnote{v}} &
    3840x2160 &
    120 Hz & \\
    Dream Glass Lead Pro &
    AR &
    ja &
    2022 &
    \$1199 & &
    90°  \xtnote{d} &
    1920x1080 & & \\
    Tilt Five &
    AR &
    nein &
    2021 &
    \$359 &
    2 x LCoS &
    110°  \xtnote{d} &
    1280x720 & & \\
    Lenovo ThinkReality A3 &
    AR &
    nein &
    2021 &
    \$1499 & & &
    1920x1080 & & \\
    HTC Vive Flow &
    VR &
    ja &
    2021 &
    \$499 &
    2 x LCD &
    100°  \xtnote{d} &
    1600x1600 &
    75 Hz & \\
    Huawei VR Glass 6DoF &
    MR &
    nein &
    2021 &
    \$620 &
    2 x LCD &
    90°  \xtnote{d} &
    1600x1600 &
    90 Hz &
    6 DoF Inside-out via 2 Kameras \\\midrule
    \multicolumn{10}{l}{%
      \xtnote*{1} Standalone,\qquad\xtnote*{2} Sehwinkel,\qquad
    \xtnote*{h} horizontal,\qquad\xtnote*{v} vertical,\qquad\xtnote*{d} diagonal}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```